# Apps for home schooling, times table help etc

Tags: software-recommendation, education

I am looking for apps to help with home schooling, such as times table games, reading and adventure fun games, science games, anything for fun learning. Are there any applications like this for Ubuntu?

Comment: Lots of that kind of material is web-based. It doesn't matter what OS you are using.

Comment: https://www.edubuntu.org/

Answer (score 1):

`gcompris` is an educational suite. Has lots of games and activities for typing, memory, pictures etc for children 2 to 10 years

For games `supertuxkart` is one of the best racing game for linux similar to super mario kart on other platforms. Another game similar to a super mario is `supertux`. `assultcube` is a first person shooter game with good fps.
`gbrainy` is a brain teaser game.

`anki` is a flashcard app for memorizing stuff. `gperiodic` and `gchemtable` are periodic table for chemistry. `bkem` for drawing chemical structures. `lybniz` helps you plot graphs for your basic maths.`tuxtype` and `ktouch` teach the kids to touch-type. `gcu-bin` provide most chemistry tools you might need. Do conversions with `convertall`.

`oneko` is a cat running on your screen following your mouse.

And many more

Install all this apps and games with:

```
sudo apt install gcompris supertuxkart supertux assaultcube gbrainy
sudo apt install anki bkem gperiodic tuxtype ktouch gcu-bin
```